# remove unwanted message from my web pages and posts

Tags: wordpress

each page and post on my website **styleshark.in** displays an embedded message **spread the love**. I have tried all options and still not getting where to remove it. i want to remove it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5H6JE.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have "[Sassy Social Share](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sassy-social-share/)" Plugin installed . You can change the text "spread the love " via the `Title option` in the `Standard Interface section`.